# search for a key in json data using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
data:{
key1:{
   child1:{},
   child2:{}
 }
key2:{
  child21:{}
 }
}
```

how can I get key2's child when i am not sure about key2's position?

Comment: it's an object, just use the key.

Comment: `data.key2.child21`...or `data["key2"]["child21"]` you can use variables if you don't know the key at design time.

Comment: What do you mean by position?

Comment: I want ot list all the children of given parent and in this case the given parent is key2.

Comment: Well when speaking of JSON data you'd first have to parse it.... then get the value by key.

Comment: Please provide the literal result you want to have for some sample data. You want output "child21", or "{}", or still something else?

Comment: To @ProfessorAllman's point, there is no "position" in objects. There are only keys. The order is not determined, and should not be considered fixed. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: What you posted is not JSON. Please read the [tag:json] tag description: *"Use this tag when this text format is involved, but not for native JavaScript objects."* It seems you are talking about JavaScript objects.

Comment: Also, this should help: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var keys = Object.keys(data);
```

This will return an array of strings of the key names. `["key1", "key2"]`

I think specifically you need:

```
var childnames = Object.keys(data[key2]);
```

You could turn this into an array of those objects that are it's children by:

```
var key2children = [];
for(var i=0; i< childnames.length; i++){
  key2children.push(data[key2][cildnames[i]);
}
```

EDIT Maybe this helps?:

```
//To get the children of an object
function getChildObjects(tgtobj){
    var objchildren = [];
    objectkeys = Object.keys(tgtobj);
    for(var i=0; i< objectkeys.length; i++){
      key2children.push(tgtobj[objectkeys[i]);
    }
    return objectchildren;
}

//This could be used to get the children of a child object in a function like this:
function getChildOjectsOfChildByName(tgtobj, name){
    return getChildObjects(tgtobj[name]);
}

//usage example:
var key2childojects = getChildOjectsOfChildByName(data, "key2");
```

Comment: what if this search is for child21's properties ? same code will not work.

Comment: You could build a function that takes the name of the object that is inside data as an argument...  I'll make one.

Comment: Posted.  Does this suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a for in loop and recursion to get the nested key.

```
function searchObj(obj, searVal){
    for (ii in obj){
        if(ii === searVal){
            console.log(ii, ' -- my key');
        } else{
            console.log(ii, ' -- no key here');
            searchObj(obj[ii], searVal);
        }
    }
}
searchObj(data, 'child21');
```

Comment: what if child21 is an array ?

Comment: Child21 can have any valid value. Child21 is a key/property of the data object. It a JSON string. It can't be an array.

Comment: From my understanding of the question you are trying to find a particular key/property of an object. If you are trying to determine if it is an array then you can add that in as well.